# how long should it take for ntfsclone to complete?

Tags: 16.04, windows-7, backup, ntfs-3g

I am trying to backup a Windows 7 installation from a Kubuntu 16.04 box.
The hard drive is a 320GB Toshiba directly connected to a SATA interface and has always wored well.

My initiall attempt was to use `ntfsclone` + `xz` as below:

```
ntfsclone --save-image -o - /dev/sdb3 | xz -9e -T8 > Win7-20170621.ntfsclone.xz
```

But when I reach the point of actually backing up the data, (message "Saving NTFS to image ...") it takes hours!

Then I thought I could blame `xz` and rearranged things to simply backup without any compression:

```
ntfsclone --save-image -o Win7-20170621.ntfsclone.xz /dev/sdb3
```

But no better luck. It still takes hours.

My box is a quite good i7-7700K with 16GB DDR4 RAM and Kubuntu is running from a 240GB Kingston SSD.
Monitoring system resources I see average CPU usage is only about 15% (with 100% on a single core from time to time).
Used RAM is never above 3GB.

Disk usage from `sdb3` is about 2.5MB/s - that is quite below what `hdparm -Tt` shows for this drive. I even tried copying files and speed is a quite good 40 to 60MB/s.
The destination drive usage is very low. From time to time I see some spikes of 5MB/s or so.

Is it normal?
I see people across the internet stating that `ntfsclone` should take only a few minutes to complete.
What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the image saved? Is it the same partition you've been trying to clone? If that's the case, it will keep on going until it runs out of space.

Comment: I am saving the image on a pretty fast USB-3.0 external hard drive. Thanks for asking @mikewhatever

Comment: Still happens: 25% backed up in 1h 25 min --> ~6 hrs total for 49,1GB used in a 339GB filesystem. Funny thing is: Yesterday I backed up a different Win 10 on similar hardware with the same 20.04LTS release of Ubuntu, it was much faster (factor 2?).

If only someone would offer a solution. I have no idea, unfortunately.